# Multi Domain Kerberos configuration with 1 way trust

Tags: kerberos

I had configured Multi Domain Kerberos SSO for documentum client with 1 way trust between the domains... But while logging into client, i am getting the below error...

```
[DEBUG] Thu Oct 25 02:56:04 PDT 2012 jcsi.kerberos: resetting state...
[DEBUG] Thu Oct 25 02:56:04 PDT 2012 jcsi.kerberos: principal = 'HTTP/mdk1waytrustd3.wtmdk1waydom3.com'
[DEBUG] Thu Oct 25 02:56:04 PDT 2012 jcsi.kerberos: realm = 'WTMDK1WAYDOM3.COM'
[DEBUG] Thu Oct 25 02:56:04 PDT 2012 jcsi.kerberos: Found name servers using JNDI
[DEBUG] Thu Oct 25 02:56:04 PDT 2012 jcsi.kerberos: mdk1waytrustd2.wtmdk1waydom2.com (10.31.70.183)
[DEBUG] Thu Oct 25 02:56:04 PDT 2012 jcsi.kerberos: mdk1waytrustd1.wtmdk1waydom1.com (10.31.69.52)
[DEBUG] Thu Oct 25 02:56:04 PDT 2012 jcsi.kerberos: MDK1WAYTRUSTD3.WTMDK1WAYDOM3.COM (10.31.70.184)
[DEBUG] Thu Oct 25 02:56:04 PDT 2012 jcsi.kerberos: mdk1waytrustd4.wtmdk1waydom4.com (10.31.71.34)
[DEBUG] Thu Oct 25 02:56:04 PDT 2012 jcsi.kerberos: corpinba8.corp.emc.com (10.30.48.37)
[DEBUG] Thu Oct 25 02:56:04 PDT 2012 jcsi.kerberos: corpgefr3.corp.emc.com (152.62.196.10)
[DEBUG] Thu Oct 25 02:56:04 PDT 2012 jcsi.kerberos: The old JCSI Kerberos code for the Windows LSA is now disabled by default;
if you really want it (rather than the new WinSSPI code) you must set
        -Djcsi.kerberos.lsa.enable=true
[DEBUG] Thu Oct 25 02:56:04 PDT 2012 jcsi.kerberos: Creating LSA credential cache
[DEBUG] Thu Oct 25 02:56:04 PDT 2012 jcsi.kerberos: Could not locate default cache: com.dstc.security.kerberos.KerberosException: Could not create credential store com.dstc.security.kerberos.KerberosException: Native in-memory credential cache not supported on this platform (Windows Server 2008 R2)
[DEBUG] Thu Oct 25 02:56:04 PDT 2012 jcsi.kerberos: login succeeded
[DEBUG] Thu Oct 25 02:56:04 PDT 2012 jcsi.kerberos: loaded InputStream based keytab at time 1351158964992 m/secs, 5 entries
[DEBUG] Thu Oct 25 02:56:04 PDT 2012 jcsi.kerberos: binding principal to subject
[DEBUG] Thu Oct 25 02:56:04 PDT 2012 jcsi.kerberos: binding credentials to subject
```

Can someone can help me in overcoming this issue???

Comment: Where is the error? I see only debug output!

Answer (score 1):

Root caused due to 'krb5login.conf' using dstc login module rather than the old sun.security.auth module. Try modify your krb5login.conf as follows and you will be happy. :)

```
HTTP-mdk1waytrustd3-wtmdk1waydom3-com    
{
com.dstc.security.kerberos.jaas.KerberosLoginModule required
principal="HTTP/mdk1waytrustd3.wtmdk1waydom3.com"
noTGT=true
debug=true
refreshKrb5Config=true
useKeyTab=true
storeKey=true
doNotPrompt=true
useTicketCache=false
isInitiator=false
realm="WTMDK1WAYDOM3.COM"
keyTab="C:\\keytab location\\keytab.keytab";
};
```